# Looping several LISTS in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

This program was built using python 3

```
# Here are my lists
header = ['item_num','item_name','item_price']
item1 = ['001','scissors', 2.59]
item2 = ['002','tape', 1.99]
item3 = ['003','paper', .79]
item4 = ['004','glue', .99]

# Display Header
print(header[0], "\t", header[1], "\t\t", header[2])
print("----------", "\t", "----------", "\t\t", "----------")

# I would like to print them in a loop for efficiency instead of a static 
# print statement such as the one below.

print(item1[0], "\t\t", item1[1], "\t\t", item1[2])
print(item2[0], "\t\t", item2[1], "\t\t\t", item2[2])
print(item3[0], "\t\t", item3[1], "\t\t\t", item3[2])
print(item4[0], "\t\t", item4[1], "\t\t\t", item4[2])
```

So I tried to design a loop that would take care of this. Where x is dynamically changing to represent the next list datatype.

```
# if x in range(6)
#      print(item(x)[0], "\t\t", item(x)[1], "\t\t", item(x)[2])

# So I am a bit stuck!
# Your help is highly appreciated and if there is a different solution that
# works better, I am ready to learn!
```

Comment: Any time you find yourself creating variables with numeric names like that, they should probably be a single list. `items = [['001','scissors', 2.59], ['002','tape', 1.99], ['003','paper', .79], ['004','glue', .99]]`.

Comment: This is certainly helpful, thanks for providing me with some real world techniques!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
for item in [item1, item2, item3, item4]:
  print(item[0], '\t\t', item[1], '\t\t', item[2])
```

I am creating a "list of lists" `[item1, item2, item3, item4]` and traversing it

Comment: That worked great!  Thanks Atul for all your help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

A more Pythonic and readable way would be to use tuples and sequence unpacking:

```
for num, name, price in item1, item2, item3, item4:
    print(num, '\t\t', name, '\t\t', price)
```

Comment: Wow!  I like this too!, it's easy to explain to a someone the declared variables in the loop and their associations.  Thanks blhsing!